# RxJava android not working and can't compile code

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to learn RXjava for android, so I have done the following:

1) I have downloaded the jar file of rxandroid-0.24.jar ,
   rxandroid-framework-0.24.jar
   2) added files to libs folder in android studio
   3) add lib dependency to android studio, please check following
   screenshot:

[image]

4) tried some code in my fragment and it doesn't seem to see rxandroid, please check following code:

```
import rx.Observable;
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Observable.from("one","two","three","four","five")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .sobscribe(/* an Observer */);
}
```

I am using this tutorial https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module

Can anyone please help and tell me what is missing here?

Comment: check if the line: compile files('libs/rxandroid-0.24.0.jar') is in your build.gradle file under dependencies. If not add it and sync with gradle files.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the import for the Android schedulers; they're in a different package to the rest of RxJava:

```
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
```